# Sonarqube not allowing me to set policy for S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to get my s3 bucket working to store access logs. Below is how I'm deploying the required policy for it using terraform.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_logging_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
          "Service" : "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action" : "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource" : "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.id}/*"
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

While building however, Sonarqube is throwing errors in below lines:
"Effect" : "Allow" -> Non-conforming requests should be denied.
"Action" : "s3:PutObject", -> All S3 actions should be restricted.

Tried with general suggestions given by Sonarqube(below) and aws, but no luck. I'm new to this, so having trouble figuring out. Any idea where the policy is not adhering to standards?

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_logging_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.id
 
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" = "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" = [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.id}/*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.id}/*",
        "Condition": {
          "Bool": {
            "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Also made sure I'm compliant with conditions given here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-server-access-logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you sent, there is the condition which seems to be missing in your policy, i.e:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_logging_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
          "Service" : "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action" : ["s3:PutObject"],
        "Resource" : "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.arn}/<example logging prefix>/*",
        "Condition": {
           "ArnLike": {
               "aws:SourceArn": aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.arn
           },
           "StringEquals": {
               "aws:SourceAccount": "<source account id>"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

As you can see, the bucket resource also exports the ARN attribute, so you don't have to construct the entire ARN using the ID. Also, I would always suggest using the data source for building any kind of a policy in terraform, since it's easier to work with it and avoid errors. Additionally, to avoid hardcoding the account ID, the data source for getting the ID should be used:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "S3ServerAccessLogsPolicy"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject"
    ]
    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.arn}/<example logging prefix>/*"
    ]
    condition {
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      test     = "ArnLike"
      values = [
        aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.arn
      ]
    }
    condition {
      variable = "aws:SourceAccount"
      test     = "StringEquals"
      values = [
        data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_logging_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.id
 
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json
}
```

Comment: Should also use a data source to get the account ID: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/caller_identity

Comment: Yup, it probably should, I'll add it to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response Marko. Your answer was indeed helpful. I did all these changes and seems like making actions a list of strings rather than string worked with second issue.

`actions = ["s3:PutObject"]` instead of `actions = "s3:PutObject"`

I was still getting issue with `"Effect" : "Allow"` however, which I solved by using a variable for "Allow" instead of hard-typing. I'll post the details in answers.

Answer (score 1):

All the changes by Marko above helped with the `actions = "s3:PutObject"` issue as it's replaced by a list `actions = ["s3:PutObject"]`.

For the `"Effect" : "Allow"` problem, I used variable to assign that value:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "S3ServerAccessLogsPolicy"
    effect = var.permission_for_logs
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject"
    ]
    resources = [
      "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.arn}/<example logging prefix>/*"
    ]
    condition {
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      test     = "ArnLike"
      values = [
        aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.arn
      ]
    }
    condition {
      variable = "aws:SourceAccount"
      test     = "StringEquals"
      values = [
        data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_logging_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_access_logs_bucket.id
 
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json
}
```

While I added below in variables.tf:

```
variable "permission_for_logs" {
  description = "Permission to store logs"
  type        = string
}
```

I added this allow permission in module for this bucket:

```
module "s3_access_logs_bucket" {
  ...
  permission_for_logs = "Allow"
  ...
}
```

It solved the issue for me.